# Save a Markdown (not R Markdown) file as a PDF in RStudio without abusing previews?

Tags: pdf, markdown, rstudio

I have written a markdown file. Not R Markdown, plain old .md Markdown. I have done this in RStudio. I want to save this as a PDF file. Where is the option for this in RStudio? Every option that I can see is about previewing rather than saving. I can preview the PDF and then cheat by saving that preview, but that doesn't strike me as the intended solution.
[image: RStudio Toolbar]